# What is the actual purpose of return keyword in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In first stored procedure code I didn't mentioned `Return` key word at the end of code but still I get result set as output returned by the stored procedure.

But in second example code taken from Microsoft site, `Return` keyword is mentioned at end of code. I am confused about when to use keyword `Return` in a stored procedure, because in the first code without `Return` word I am getting result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspProductList
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        product_name, 
        list_price
    FROM 
        production.products
    ORDER BY 
        product_name;
END;
```

---

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  

IF OBJECT_ID('Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD', 'P') IS NOT NULL  
   DROP PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD;  
GO  

CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD  
AS    
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  

   SELECT LastName, SalesYTD  
   FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS sp  
   JOIN HumanResources.vEmployee AS e ON e.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID  

   RETURN  
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server `RETURN` is design for indicating user defined success/failure code to a caller.

Both your procedures are returning 0 (default value).

Try:

```
DECLARE @return_status int;  
EXEC @return_status = uspProductList; 
SELECT @return_status;  -- 0
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks.I got the point. Shall I conclude my understanding as Return key word has nothing to do with actually returning the result set.It is just user defined success/failure code to a caller and don't play decisive role in deciding if sp should return the result set or not.

Comment: @DevdasVivek, your understanding is correct. A `RETURN` statement exits the stored procedure immediately and, if a value is specified, returns the specified value as the stored procedure return code. If no value is specified, the return code is based on the highest error severity encountered during proc execution (i.e. `-(ERROR_SEVERITY() - 10)`).